# How can i optimize my code by reducing the looping and conditioning

Tags: python, algorithm

Here's my problem:

> Given a list of numbers and the number 'k', return whether any two numbers from the list add up to 'k'

For example, given `[1,2,5,6]` where `k` is 7, return `True` since 2+5 is 7.

Here's my code; I'd like some help on how to vectorize it.

```
L = [3,4,1]
k = 5
for i in L:
    for j in L:
        if i+j == k:
            print("True")
            break
    if i+j == k:
        break
```

Comment: What do you mean by vectorize? What specifically do you want your code to do that it isn't already doing? As an aside, your code fails the case where `L = [4]` and `k = 8`. I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

Vectorization doesn't seem like it would help here.

However, I propose a new algorithm that reduces complexity to O(N) from O(N^2):

```
L = [3,4,1]
Lset = set(L)
k = 5

for x in L:
    if k - x in Lset:
        print("True")
        break
```

I think the algorithm is fairly self-explanatory! :) It basically iterates through `L` and, for each number, checks if its "complimentary" (the number required to satisfy `x + complimentary == k`) is present in the list (converted to a set for lower membership check cost).

If you don't want to count cases like `L = [1]`, `k = 2`, you can do this:

```
for x in L:
    if k - x in Lset:
        if k - x == x and L.count(x) < 2:
            continue
        print("True")
        break
```

Comment: this doesn't work, since a number may be counted twice. For example `L = [1, 4]` and `K = 2`

Comment: @TheoWalton the solution in the question does as well

Comment: I would argue this algorithm isn't self-explanatory to someone new enough to post this question. Some explanation would be good. Writing up an explanation would also prove to yourself why your code doesn't work at a few edge cases.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Your additional code just complicates things though. And you left the code that breaks at the edge cases in your answer.

Comment: @JordanSinger I added an explanation. Also, if you look at OP's code, it works for their needs and does not consider such cases. Therefore, I did not include these cases in my answer either.

Answer (score -1):

use itertools.combinations(L, 2) to give you all the 2 length sequences